# How to run .exe with .bat file in same dir

Tags: batch-file

I am making a program that will auto run files for me but i want to run a .exe file from the same place or directory that the run.bat file is!

I have bin tring like this:

```
:FarCry 2
echo Starting game...
start FarCry2.exe
pause
:exit
```

But it wont start! why?

Comment: is this running off via UNC path? Have you tried running the .bat from a command prompt instead of double-clicking it, yada yada yada? e.g. ... what have you done to try and debug this?

Comment: try `echo %cd%` before pause to see what is your current path and check if there is **FarCry2.exe** file

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
start "" "%~dp0farcry2.exe"
```

which should prepend the batch's drive&directory to the executable name.

Adding the empty "window title" is simply common practice to overcome `START`'s strange syntax.

Answer (score 0):

if FarCry2.exe is in the same folder than your run.dat replace FarCry2.exe by ./FarCry2.exe